# Set Up Vanity URL

Tags: force.com-sites, custom-url

I have been asked to set up a vanity url. Essentially, the force.com page should point to a more user friendly web address. There needs to be one for internal users and one for external users. I have no idea what I'm doing. I've read through some documentation. From one I understand this needs to be either a custom url or an apex class. I've been instructed no to write code, so I'd like to avoid the apex class, if possible. There is already a site set up for the force.com url. When I try to set up the custom url, I'm told we need to register the CNAME. I have also been asked what the url should point to? I have no idea.
 Any help would be appreciated at this point.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This article will walk you through it:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000205653&language=en_US&type=1

Basically, if you want the site to point to www.mycoolsite.com then you would register that domain if you don't already have it, and then point the new domain to your force.com site by updating the CNAME using the unique name SF provides e.g. 
www.mycoolsite.com.00d200000005pikra.live.siteforce.com

You can then create a Domain record in SFDC and point your force.com site at that domain bu updating the Site Info for that Site.

If you want to use HTTPS you may need to get a SSL Certificate and upload that to SFDC as well.

Comment: Excellent. This is basically what I was thinking from everything I've read. Nice to have confirmation. Thanks